# why don't i see the output?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I don't see the message `Singleton Class` when i run the following code. Why is that ?

```
ob = Object.new
class << ob
 def func
   "Singleton class"
 end
end
ob.func
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method returns a string. To display it you must use `puts`.

If you run this in `irb` you will get the resulting string displayed since in that mode every return value is automatically printed.

Comment: earlier i had been doing this in irb !

Comment: `irb` is helpful that way, but stand-alone programs do not have that automatic-print facility.